# How to deal with custom commands on google assistant SDK

Tags: python, pi-3

I installed google assistant SDK and followed hot word example. I have some code posted [here](https://github.com/rpetrenko/raspberry/blob/master/rpi_google/hotword.py#L49) on Github.

Everything works, but when Google doesn't know what to respond it issues voice command:

> Sorry, I can't help.

I have got speech to text and my command is processed by my custom code, but Google's response is annoying.

How can I disable that response?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than a month old now, but once you get the ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED event you can call `assistant.stop_conversation()`, to stop the conversation before Google tries to interpret it as an Assistant command. When `assistant.stop_conversation()` is called it will go back to listening for "Ok, Google."